Float number console output via crt_printf in MASM
I need to output float number to console using masm assembly. I decided to use crt_printf from msvcrt.lib library, but instead of my number 0.000000 appears when I run my program.
Here is my code:
.386
.model flat, stdcall    
option casemap :none   

include     \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include     \masm32\include\windows.inc 
includelib  \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
 
include     \masm32\include\user32.inc 
includelib  \masm32\lib\user32.lib      

include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc 
includelib  \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib

.data
fmto db "%f",0 

n dd 0.2

.code
main:
    mov eax, n
    invoke crt_printf, ADDR fmto, eax, 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

end main


%f takes a double not a float as per the usual C language varargs promotions. See also msdn

Ok, I've changed %f to %e, and got 5.164076e-315. The result depends on n value, but it always is something very small.

%e also expects a double. You can not print a float. See also the first part of this answer Change your n to be a double (use dq I guess) or convert it at runtime.

Apparently masm uses real8 Obviously you won't be able to feed that through eax and possibly not even invoke. You might have to do things manually.

Even if I use dq instead of dd with n, still small number is printed. Maybe, I cannot just write 0.2 after n dq? (Also I excluded eax usage from the code, now it gives ADDR n directly).

ADDR n is wrong as that passes the address while it needs to be passed by value. Try with real8 and invoke crt_printf, ADDR fmto, n (what was the trailing zero supposed to do anyway?)

Oh, thank you very much! With n dq 0.2 and invoke crt_printf, ADDR fmto, coeff, 0 it works well. Yep, the trailing zero does absolutely nothing, I thought for some reason that every invoke must have it, but it seems it mustn't.
